# How do I take a screenshot from a YouTube video?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, youtube, screen-capture

My Prt Sc button is on the same button as my Home button. The Prt Sc is circled and under the word Home. I assume that you push Shift+Home to get Prt Sc to work. That is how it has worked in past iterations of Windows, my current version being Windows 7.

So, I press Shift+Home and open Paint, Photoshop and Word. I then press paste and nothing comes out. I've done it repeatedly with the same results.

I've looked up the process with Windows Help and it tells me to do exactly what I have done. In addition, somewhere in here, it was suggested to open Windows Media Player and take the screen print from there, which I have done, with the same results. I have also tried taking screen prints from VLC media player.

The version of Firefox I am using when I screen print from YouTube is 37.0.2. Any help I can receive is well appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: TD.512 is spot on. Your other option is to use the [Snipping Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool). Interestingly, the Snipping Tool freezes the Youtube video when you click 'New' to make your snip - didn't know this before!

Comment: @AndiMohr, good point, completely forgot about the Snipping Tool

Comment: I like http://www.picpick.org/en/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I take screenshots of YouTube videos in full screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/471460/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-youtube-videos-in-full-screen)

Answer (score 2):

Having had lots of PCs, `Fn+Home` should work, assuming you have the Function key.

EDIT: As Andi Mohr said, You could also use the snipping tool instead of instant screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Pause the video at the frame you want to take a screenshot of, and just hit alt+printscreen on your keyboard (to take a screenshot of your current window and place it into your clipboard).

Then, open MSPaint, and hit CTRL+V (to paste). Cut out the browser area and modify the picture to your heart's content. Save it as jpg and you're set.