# How can I make a bookmarklet to unhide youtube controls?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, youtube, bookmarklet

I found a command line to make a bookmarklet that hides the progress/controls bar on a YouTube video, so now I can pause the video and see the full image and take screenshots. Now I'm wondering how can I do the inverse, make a bookmarklet to reverse this command and unhide the progress/controls bar. I tried to figure it out myself but my knowledge in code and javascript is practically null.

Does anybody know what javascript string would work?
The original command is:

```
javascript:(function(){var goaway=".ytp-gradient-bottom,.ytp-gradient-top,.ytp-chrome-top,
.ytp-chrome-bottom{display:none;}";
if("\v"=="v"){document.createStyleSheet().cssText=goaway}
else{var tag=document.createElement("style");
tag.type="text/css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
tag[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance=="string")?"innerText":"innerHTML"]=goaway}})();
```

Comment: doesn't this answer your question : https://superuser.com/a/1052944/777184

Comment: @Madhubala, I believe no... that are the instructions to make the bookmarklet that hides the progress/controls bar (toolbar), and it says "To RESTORE all toolbars: refresh the page" I wish to restore all toolbars with a bookmarklet, not by refreshing the page as this is disruptive and usually plays the video from the beginning and not where I left off.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly such a script existed on reddit prior your question:

[Bookmarklet to hide/unhide all YouTube Progress/Toolbars with one click : youtube](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/avk4fl/bookmarklet_to_hideunhide_all_youtube/)

> To ADD the bookmarklet to your browser:
>
> Highlight the text in the following codeblock:
>
> javascript:(function(){var
> ytp_element_css=document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-chrome-bottom");var
> ytp_element_style=window.getComputedStyle(ytp_element_css[0]);var
> ytp_element_display=ytp_element_style.getPropertyValue("display");var
> ytp_elements=".ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom,.ytp-gradient-top,.ytp-gradient-bottom";var
> ytp_css="empty";var
> x=document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-chrome-bottom").length;if(ytp_element_display=="none"){var
> ytpon="{display:block;}";ytp_css=ytp_elements+ytpon}else{var
> ytpoff="{display:none;}";ytp_css=ytp_elements+ytpoff}var
> tag=document.createElement("style");tag.type="text/css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);tag[(typeof
> document.body.style.WebkitAppearance=="string")?"innerText":"innerHTML"]=ytp_css})();
>
> Drag the highlighted text to your browser bookmarks toolbar.
>
> *OPTIONAL* Rename the bookmarklet for clarity.
>
> To USE the bookmarklet:
>
> Load any YouTube video.
>
> Click on the bookmarklet.
>
> All the progress/toolbars will disappear (or reappear if they were
> already gone).